# Запятая при определениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Такими героями, неприметными, беззащитными и обществу неинтересными**(#) **книги русских писателей изобилуют.**

Нужна ли запятая на месте "#"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Такими героями, неприметными, беззащитными и обществу неинтересными, книги русских писателей изобилуют.**

> Обособляется согласованное определение, состоящее из нескольких слов и относящееся к предшествующему имени существительному. (http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_174)

Можно считать, что эти определения конкретизируют общее значение местоимения *такими*. Это дает нам право выделить их с помощью тире:

**Такими героями — неприметными, беззащитными и обществу неинтересными — книги русских писателей изобилуют.**

Ритмически предложение неудачное (попробуйте его произнести вслух). Как вариант могу предложить такую правку:

**Такими героями — неприметными, беззащитными и обществу неинтересными — книги русских писателей просто изобилуют.**